# How can I get a specific numbered `man` page?

Tags: man

I just added the following line to my `init.el`:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "M-o") 'man)
```

but it is not enough. Before, if I wanted to perform the shell command equivalent to `man 2 read` I would do `M-x man RET 2 read`. Emacs doesn't to like the numbers and spaces, and takes multiple seconds to load it up, whereas `M-x man RET read` is instantaneous, but not what I want.

What is an easy way to grab a specific numbered man page?

Something where I can see all the reads would be ideal, so that I could do something like `M-n` within `man-mode` to browse through my options, or even something that can see whether I'm in a `shell` buffer, or in `C` mode and grab the relevant man page.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by “Emacs doesn't like the numbers”? Typing “2 read” into the prompt works just fine for me; there’s no extra delay compared to just typing “read”. The space doesn’t do anything unusual either.

Comment: Typing `2` with a space afterward makes emacs hang for several seconds. If I type in `read`, it won't show up on my screen, but after hitting `RET`, in an indeterministic amount of time, the man page will load.

Comment: That sounds like an unrelated problem; perhaps something to do with how you have set up completion. Comment out that part of your init file and try again without whatever extra completion stuff you had set up. Then at least you can ask questions about the right thing.

Comment: Ah. My init file doesn't have anything to do with completion. I'm running on MacOS Ventura, and installed as a homebrew cask.

Comment: `M-x man RET 2 read RET` works fine for me: no delays. So does `M-x man RET read(2) RET`. No perceived difference in the timing (but I did not profile them).

Comment: Related Question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76097655/324105

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions I have found since posting:

```
M-x man RET command-name(man-page-number) RET
```

a.ka., put the number in parentheses, or via

`M-x customize RET` change `Man-switches` to `-a` and use `M-n` to go through man pages. Found via [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Man-Page.html#:%7E:text=To%20make%20use%20of%20this,is%20the%20M%2Dx%20woman%20command.).